# SVG not showing when using pattern to mask an image

Tags: svg, d3.js

I am working with the D3 library.

I want to present an image in the middle of the screen, masked by a circular path (or a `circle` element).  Similar to what is shown in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/djjupa/yjE8K/), but in the middle of the screen.

I read that something like this can be accomplished using svg's patterns. So here is some of the D3 code I am using to append an image into a pattern:

```
  var circularNode = vis.selectAll("g.node")
                    .data(userNode)
                .enter().append("svg:g")
                    .attr("class", "node")
                    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
                    ;



   var defs = circularNode.append("svg:defs");


   var pattern = defs.append("svg:pattern")
                .attr("id", "User001" )
                .attr("patternUnits", "userSpaceOnUse")
                .attr("patternTransform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")" + " scale(1,1)"; })
                .attr("x", 0)
                .attr("y", 0)
                .attr("width", 1600)
                .attr("height", 1160)
                //.attr("viewBox", "-10 -10 16 10")
            ;           



   var userImagePath = pattern.append("svg:image")
                .attr("x", width/2)
                .attr("y", height/2)
                .attr("width", 179)
                .attr("height", 132)
                .attr("xlink:href", "http://www.bittbox.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/04/free_hires_wood_texture_5.jpg")
                ;


var path = circularNode.append("svg:path")
                .attr("d", "M0,0 a16,16 0 1 1 -100,0 16,16 0 1 1 100,0 z")
                .attr("fill", function(d){ return "url(#User001)";})
                ;
```

The problem is that nothing shows on the screen with the code obtained. This is the resulting svg when inspecting the page, also seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/djjupa/dGA6j/):

```
    <svg id="graph" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%">
        <g class="node" transform="translate(480,400)">
           <defs>
              <pattern id="User001" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" width="1600" height="1160">
                   <image x="480" y="400" width="179" height="132" xlink:href="http://www.bittbox.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/04/free_hires_wood_texture_5.jpg"></image>
              </pattern>
           </defs>
           <path d="M0,0 a16,16 0 1 1 -100,0 16,16 0 1 1 100,0 z" fill="url(#User001)"></path>
        </g>
    </svg>
```

I think the problem might be on the dimensions and the position of the image in relation to the pattern or the path, but I am having a very hard time understanding how the svg path element work and how to position it right, even after reading the documentation.

Can someone explain how pattern, image and path/circle work together, and explain  why the masked image won't show in this case?

This is a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/djjupa/JLsSu/). I just don't understand why it won't work with the D3 code shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared the wrong width and height for the image used in the pattern. It's too small, so nothing shows. Change the code to this:

```
var userImagePath = pattern.append("svg:image")
            .attr("x", width/2)
            .attr("y", height/2)
            .attr("width", 1600)
            .attr("height", 1600)
            .attr("xlink:href", "http://www.bittbox.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/04/free_hires_wood_texture_5.jpg")
            ;
```

In addition, you need to set `patternTransform` on the pattern itself so the image is translated and shown completely, just like in the working example:

```
var pattern = defs.append("svg:pattern")
            .attr("id", "User001" )
            .attr("patternUnits", "userSpaceOnUse")
            .attr("patternTransform", "translate(480,400)")
            .attr("x", 0)
            .attr("y", 0)
            .attr("width", 1600)
            .attr("height", 1160)
        ;
```

You do seem to have this code already, but your generated SVG doesn't contain that attribute. Note also that the SVG you've posted here and in your non-working jsfiddle are different.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Lars. You are right, the image was to small and the position of the pattern was off. But I still don't understand how image and pattern work together in terms of positioning and size. What happens if you wrap that `<pattern>`element inside a group with transformed `<g transform="translate(480,400)>`?

Comment: In short, I want to present the image centered inside a circle.

Comment: Then the pattern transform would need to be by half the image width and height.

Comment: Thanks, Lars! After reading around and based on your last answer, I managed to do what I was thinking about. Here's another [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/djjupa/gfqS8/2/)